# Yaw from quaternion with non zero pitch

Tags: imu

- If IMU is gravity aligned, pitch is zero and yaw is unobservable.
- If IMU is not gravity aligned, pitch is non zero and yaw is observable.

**Question:** given an input quaternion with non null pitch, how do you extract the observable yaw?

Comment: Your question is not well defined. Do you assume 0 roll? Do you assume orientation is given by yaw, followed by pitch?